# Override a standard button in Salesforce page

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I'm trying to override a standard button (delete) in a Salesforce page. I overrode it with a Visualforce Page but the problem I'm facing is the pop up blocker.

The purpose of overriding the button is to ask the user whether he/she wants to delete the file and do the deletion on the third party host.

Is there any way I can either stop the pop up blocker or use another overriding approach?
My visualforce page contains a js script that will open a pop up window. I'm wondering if I can put this js script in a different place!

```
<apex:page standardController="" showheader="false" sidebar="false"> 
    <apex:includeScript value=""/>
    <apex:includeScript value=""/>
        <script language="javascript"> 
            var caseStatus = "{!s__c}";
            try{
                sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
                var isPortalUser = sforce.apex.execute('e','r',{}); 
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e)
            }

                if(caseStatus == "A"){
                window.open('{!$Label.FTP_Attachment_Pro_URL}/sforce/ftp/Delete.aspx?ID={!ENZ__FTPAttachment__c.Id}&OrgID={!$Organization.Id}&SFUrl={!$Label.API_URL}/{!$Organization.Id}&SFSessionID={!$Api.Session_ID}',500,600);
            window.location = '{!$Label.SF_Base_URL}/{!ENZ__FTPAttachment__c.Case__c}';

            }
               else{
                    window.location = '{!$La}';
                    window.alert("a"+ caseStatus);
                } 

    </script> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Are you using the confirm() function or a popup window? As I think the former shouldn't get blocked.

Comment: please check the question again. I added the salesforce page that is used in overriding. sorry I removed all parameters for privacy issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use window.open as that can get blocked as it is a popup.

If you don't want a fancy confirmation box you can use javascript confirm function

```
if (confirm('are you sure you want to delete?')) {
  // delete
} else {
  // error
}
```

If you need fancy way of asking for it use a modal box instead as seen on http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ there is many available on the net that are easy to use and can work with other libraries or without any (the jqueryui link is merely to illustrate the dialog box.

Here is a good one with a demo as a confirmation modal box (last demo on the page)

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry though I didn't make my question clear. My window.Open method opens an asp.net page with passed variables to delete the selected file. I will add the complete window.Open part in the question. Please check again. Thanks.

Comment: It is irrelevant, as long as you are using window.open the popup blocker will stop your page. Like I stated your only way out is using a modal box, in which you can load your ASP page if you want. The modal box can also contain an iframe so you can load whatever you want. Popup blocker look for window.open calls and cancel them, no other way around it but to change the way you are displaying the content.

Comment: I cant load the asp.net page in the iframe. I'm using the same way they do it in the demo. If I hard code the link the page works, but if I use a var that has values based on each item the page doesnt work. I also tried to set my src to www.google.com the iframe doesnt show anything.